# Firebase orderByChild with path and equalTo boolean doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Alright, so I have my data structure in the realtime database looking something like this:

[image]

and when I run a query like this:

```
database.ref('access_lists').orderByChild('95577307/read').equalTo(true)
```

I receive absolutely nothing from the query. As far as I can tell this should work, but I'm kind of at a loss at why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have a key inside another key that's why you get no value, if the numbers `95577307, ...` have a purpose but don't need to be a value use it as a key by changing the way you are structuring your data:

```
access_lists: {
  95577307: {
    name: 'FelixJar1'
    read: true
    write: true
  }
}
```

This would also help you sort/filter users that have read/write equalTo(true). 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures

==========================================

## EDITED TO ANSWER YOUR REPLY

This is how Firebase does it:

```
"posts": {
  "ts-functions": {
    "metrics": {       <===== it's the same key name
      "views" : 1200000,
      "likes" : 251000,
      "shares": 1200,
    },
    "title" : "Why you should use TypeScript for writing Cloud Functions",
    "author": "Doug",
  },
  "android-arch-3": {
    "metrics": {       <===== it's the same key name
      "views" : 900000,
      "likes" : 117000,
      "shares": 144,
    },
    "title" : "Using Android Architecture Components with Firebase Realtime Database (Part 3)",
    "author": "Doug",
  }
},
```

Because they have a key name `metrics` they can index it inside firebase rules and also be able to filter/sort/order values example: `metrics/views`

You on the other hand have `995055869, 950336178....`

Comment: The structure matters, the keys represent a different item, the numbers under the key will be each user/group with their rights for that specific map. According to their documentation this should work: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: Updated answer to reply to your comment

Comment: Crap, guess I'm back to square one. Thanks.